# React(Typescript) onchange event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In My React Component I have Radio input

```html
<input type="radio" onChange={changeData}>
```

and

```js
function changeData(e: any) {}
```

How can I specify event type I don't want to use any.
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshot of error?

Comment: I have added screenshot

Answer (score 14):

Check this out

```
changeData = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
    .....
}
```

Comment: for radio inputs I get this error
Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: RadioChangeEvent) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'RadioChangeEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>': currentTarget, bubbles, cancelable, defaultPrevented, and 7 more.

Answer (score 0):

```
changeData = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => { // code }
```

Comment: for radio inputs I get this error Type '(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: RadioChangeEvent) => void'. Types of parameters 'event' and 'e' are incompatible. Type 'RadioChangeEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>': currentTarget, bubbles, cancelable, defaultPrevented, and 7 more.

Comment: what about now? still same?

Comment: can you search for 'RadioChangeEvent' and replace it with some valid type?

Answer (score 0):

One might want to write it this way:

```
const changeData: React.ChangeEventHandler | undefined = 
  (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {}
```

and then

```
<input type="radio" onChange={changeData}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
changeData = (event: Event) => {
      const { value } = event.target as unknown as { value: boolean, };
      setState(value);
};
  
<input type='radio' onChange={changeData} />
```

And the squeegee lines will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the event type as React.ChangeEvent:

```
const changeData = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // your implementation here
};

<input type="radio" onChange={changeData} />
```

The React.ChangeEvent type is a generic type that represents a change event in a DOM element. The HTMLInputElement type represents an HTML  element.